# Using the "or" operator with strings in an "if" statement

Tags: c#, string

is there anyway of fixing this statement

```
if (sAwnser == ("hello" || "Hello" || "hi" || "Hi" || "hey" || "Hey" || "Hay" || "hey"))
{

}
```

it comes up with the error

```
Operator '||' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'string'
```

if anyone can help it would be much appreciated

Comment: Perhaps you also want to check case insesetive, so `hi`, `Hi`, `hI` and `HI` all match.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For avoiding so many comparisons you can do

```
var list = new string[] {"hello", "Hello", "hi", "Hi", "hey", "Hey", "Hay", "hey"};

if (list.Contains(answer))
{
}
```

Comment: You forget the close your `if` statement with `)`.

Answer (score 8):

You have to explicitly reference the first variable every time.

`sAwnser == "hello"` returns a boolean. You cannot compare a boolean to a string.

What you could do is create a collection and add all your separate strings to that. Afterwards you can use `.Contains()` on it.

Comment: @JohnH: for this one time I thought it was a Java question and explicitly changed from upper- to lowercase..

Comment: No problem.  I wouldn't normally be so picky but it might not be obvious to someone starting out with C#. :)

Comment: This is not really a precise answer. In his code he nowhere compares `sAnswer` to the string `"Hello"` - and this is also not causing the error.

Comment: @user2674389: that's because his code doesn't work at all. My answer reflects what he's trying to accomplish (it's literally the first comparison if you remove the brackets) and the error is also caused by his attempt with non-valid code. You can explain a lot if you're going to literally describe the problems with most invalid code: what's key is figuring out what the poster is trying to do and answering accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, I want to point the root of your problem;

From [`|| Operator (C# Reference)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/6373h346%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> The conditional-OR operator (||) performs a logical-OR of its **bool**
>   operands.

So you can't use `string` values with `||` operator. Both operands should be `boolean` value.

You can use LINQ with [`Enumerable.Any`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.any%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as well like;

```
string[] array = new string[] {"hello", "Hello", "hi", "Hi", "hey", "Hey", "Hay", "hey"};
if (array.Any(sAwnser.Equals))
{
   // Your sAwnser is equal one of your array values.
}
```

Answer (score 3):

One possible syntax is to create an extension method as follows:

```
public static bool EqualsAny<T>(this T input, params T[] items)
{
    return items.Contains(input);
}
```

Then you can call like this:

```
if (sAnswer.EqualsAny("hello", "Hello", "hi", "Hi", "hey", "Hey", "Hay", "hey"))
{ 
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if (sAwnser == "hello" || sAwnser == "Hello" || sAwnser == "hi" || sAwnser == "Hi" || sAwnser == "hey" || sAwnser =="Hey" || sAwnser =="Hay" || sAwnser =="hey"))
{

}
```

or you can write a seperate function to do the check

```
private bool CheckInput(String input)
        {
            String[] sAwnser = {"hello", "Hello", "hi", "Hi", "hey", "Hey", "Hay", "hey"};
            for (int i = 0; i < sAwnser.Length; i++)
            {
                if (sAwnser[i].Equals(input));
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also do:

```
var sAnswer = "hello";
var answerList = new List<string> { "HELLO", "HI", "HEY", "HAY" };
bool checkAnswer = answerList.Any(r => r == sAnswer.ToUpper());
```

using `linq`, and you could set the options to uppercase, and `.ToUpper()` the answer

Comment: That works fine for strings that contain only a-z, but lots of strings contain characters from other writing systems and they may not be canonicalizable by going to uppercase. Consider using ToUpperInvariant or using the OrdinalIgnoreCase option to Compare.

Answer (score 2):

Actually what you can do here is:

```
if ((sAwnser == "hello") || (sAwnser =="Hello") || (sAwnser =="hi") || (sAwnser =="Hi") || (sAwnser =="hey") || (sAwnser =="Hey") || (sAwnser =="Hay") || (sAwnser =="hey"))
{
 //insert code here
}
```

Compared to other suggestions, this could be the easiest way to code it, but some might think that this isn't a good practice. Anyway, have fun coding.

Comment: This was the easiest to implement, because I had to test simple stuff like `(foo == "") || (bar == "") `.

Answer (score 1):

Most programming languages don't work like that. You are actually asking it to compute `"hello" || "Hello" || etc..` and the `||` operator can not be applied to strings (what would you want the result to be, anyway?)

That the expression appears as the right hand side of a comparison is irrelevant. Consider also what would happen if that wasn't the case - what would this mean?

```
if (someBool == (true || false))
    something;
```

Should that

1. always execute, because `someBool` is always either `true` or `false`, or
2. execute only if `someBool` is `true`, because `true || false` is `true`?

Every programming language I know of (in which this is applicable) chooses the second case, and that can be generalized to other constructs that look similar (such as your example) and even more generally, looking at any sub-expression in isolation is enough to determine what it does. Choosing the first way makes it so that you have to look at a whole expression before you can determine what any of its sub-expressions might means, because their meaning may depend on something external to them.

Answer (score 0):

use .Equals() to compare strings

```
        String sAnswer = "hello";
        if( sAnswer.Equals("hello")|| sAnswer.Equals("Hi"))
            System.Console.Write("yes");
        else
             System.Console.Write("no");
```

if you don't want to do a case sensitive comparison you can uppercase you sAnswer, this way you don't have to compare with multiple variants of the same string

```
        String sAnswer1 = "hello";
        String sAnswer2 = "heLLo";
        String sAnswer3 = "HellO";
        sAnswer = sAnswer.ToUpper();
        if( sAnswer1.Equals("HELLO")) -> True
        if( sAnswer2.Equals("HELLO")) -> True
        if( sAnswer3.Equals("HELLO")) -> True
```

Also, be careful if you use the contains() method:

```
        String sAnswer = "watching";
        if( sAnswer.Contains("hi"))
```

will return you true (because watcHIng contains "hi") and i don't think you want that

Comment: This isn't Java, C# calls `.Equals()` behind the scenes when comparing strings with `==`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also declare a const string with all those values and each time you need to check just call contains method:

```
private const string test = "HellohelloHihiHeyhey";

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string UserInput = Console.ReadLine();

    if (test.Contains(UserInput))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("success!!");
    }   
}
```